# How do get the length of a video in Xamarin Forms

Tags: video, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How do I get the length of a video using Xamarin Forms? I have used the following link to get the thumbnail from a video, but I need to be able to get the video length

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119450/create-thumbnail-from-video

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I was able to use my brain and figure this out. It uses a similar method in the link:

For Android:

```
    public string VideoLength(string url)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.SetDataSource(url, new Dictionary<string, string>());
        var length = retriever.ExtractMetadata(MetadataKey.Duration);
        var lengthseconds = Convert.ToInt32(length) / 1000;
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthseconds);
        var timeformat = t.ToString();
        return timeformat.ToString();
    }
```

For IOS:

```
    public string VideoLength(string url)
    {
       AVAsset avasset = AVAsset.FromUrl((new Foundation.NSUrl(url)));
        var length = avasset.Duration.Seconds.ToString();
        var lengthseconds = Convert.ToInt32(length) / 1000;
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthseconds);
        var timeformat = t.ToString();
        return timeformat.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: In both cases, the `ToString` after the return is not needed you are basically converting a string to a string which makes it an extra line of code just return `t.ToString();` and you should be good