# how to play the list of videos in xamarin.forms using Plugin.mediamanager.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can any one help me on this I am using Plugin.MediaManager.Forms for playing the videos.

1)how to play the list of videos in xamarin forms using plugin.mediamanager.forms plugin?
2)I want make a video player to run the video a specific time (example i want to play a video A for 15 sec after that want to stop and play another video ) and span only how can i pass the duration to the video in playlist

Please help me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56952561/7794690

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/source-bindings

Comment: You can create a timer to limit the time MediaManager can play each video.and paly the list of videos you could refer to https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#play-multiple-media-items